# Android Tabs Margin/Padding

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to use tabs in my app and have a problem with my icons and text in any tab after the first (see attached image).  Is there something I am doing wrong in my layout?  Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <include layout="@layout/tab1"/>
            <include layout="@layout/tab2"/>
            <include layout="@layout/tab3"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

All 3 layouts have just a ListView root.

[image]

Comment: Solved your problem yet?